# How is the struct keyword used for OCaml compatibility in module definitions?

Tags: f#

Suppose I have a type like this:

```
type Sprite =
  {
    Position : struct (int * int)
  }
```

The hover-text for `struct` in *Ionide* says:

> struct
>
> Description
>
> Used to declare a structure type. Also used in generic parameter
> constraints.
>
> Used for OCaml compatibility in module definitions.

I am curious, what does this part mean?

> Used for OCaml compatibility in module definitions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basic OCaml module definitions have the syntax

```ml
module Module = struct
  ...
end
```

F# started as a port of OCaml but has changed a lot of the syntax at this point, but still has many things around for backwards compatibility. If you use this syntax in an F# program you will see the following warning:

> This construct is for ML compatibility. The syntax 'module ... = struct .. end' is not used in F# code. Consider using 'module ... = begin .. end'.